# Насколько правильна эта функция?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

Здравствуйте! Насколько правильна данная функция по получению имени пользователя с точки зрения выделения и чистки памяти? Нужно ли чистить память и могут ли быть какие то проблемы с данным кодом? Необходимо использовать чистый winapi, так что, std::string не вариант.

```
bool getCU(LPTSTR* usrBuf) {
    DWORD usrLen =  (sizeof(usrBuf)/sizeof(*usrBuf))+1;
    if (GetUserName((LPTSTR)usrBuf, &usrLen)) return true; else return false;
}

LPTSTR User[UNLEN+1]; 
    if (getCU(User)) MessageBox(0, (LPCTSTR)User, L"", 0);
```

Я правильно понимаю, что я передаю функции getCU указатель на LPTSTR массив который хранится в не самой функции? Это правильный подход?

Comment: "так что, std::string не вариант" -- почему? Это задание или Ваше убеждение?

Answer (score 1):

Функция совершенно бессмысленная.

1. Применять прием `sizeof(usrBuf)/sizeof(*usrBuf)` к указателю никакого смысла нет. Этот прием работает только с массивами, а не с указателями.
2. Почему передается `LPTSTR* usrBuf`? Указатель на указатель? При чем здесь указатель на указатель?
3. Переданный указатель на указатель `LPTSTR* usrBuf` силой приводится к типу `LPTSTR`? Это бессмысленно.
4. `LPTSTR User[UNLEN+1]` - это массив указателей. Что вы хотели этим сказать? Зачем вам понадобился массив указателей? И какой смысл передавать этот массив указателей в `MessageBox`, силой приведя его к `LPTSTR`?
5. Если вы пишете ваш код в терминах `T`-типов-"первертышей" (LP**T**STR), то тогда уж придерживайтесь этого правила везде. Т.е. не `L""`, а `_T("")`.

В общем код бессмыслен. В некоей изначальной форме он, очевидно, порождал простыню сообщений об ошибках от компилятора. Эти сообщения были "задушены" расстановкой явных приведений типа. Код от этого стал еще более бессмысленным.

---

```
bool getCU(LPTSTR usrBuf, DWORD usrLen) 
{
  return GetUserName(usrBuf, &usrLen);
}

...
TCHAR User[UNLEN+1]; 
if (getCU(User, sizeof User / sizeof *User))
  MessageBox(0, User, _T(""), 0);
```

Но в чем вообще заключается идея? Зачем писать некую функцию-оболочку `getCU`, которая фактически ничего не делает, кроме вызова `GetUserName`?

---

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

tstring getCU()
{
  TCHAR usrBuf[UNLEN+1]; 
  DWORD usrLen = sizeof usrBuf / sizeof *usrBuf;

  if (!GetUserName(usrBuf, &usrLen))
    usrBuf[0] = 0;

  return tstring(usrBuf);
}

...
tstring User = getCU();
if (!User.empty())
  MessageBox(0, User.c_str(), _T(""), 0);
```

Comment: 2 дня назад начал изучать C++. Почему LPTSTR User[UNLEN+1] это массив указателей? Подскажите, как сделать правильно?

Comment: @RemezW: Потому что `LPTSTR` - это сам по себе указательный тип. Соответственно `LPTSTR User[UNLEN+1]` - это массив указателей.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение! А по поводу памяти - в данном случае чистка не нужна, правильно? Идея в том, что эта функция должна вызываться в программе множество раз, а каждый раз писать лишний код не хотелось(имею ввиду объявление буферов), но я так понимаю, что разницы не будет)

Comment: @RemezW: О какой именно "чистке" идет речь? В коде нет никаких выделений динамической памяти. Значит и освобождений динамической памяти делать не нужно.

Comment: Еще такой вопрос, есть ли возможность вернуть имя пользователя в качестве результата функции? Первоначально я пытался сделать именно это. @AnT